# Python with Scrapy and Selenium get JavaScript generate content

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, scrapy

I'm using `Python` with `Selenium` and `Firefox` to get some content. The web site `HTML` is following:

```html
<html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">

<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onResize="resize();" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <iframe id="iframe" align="center" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" src="" style="margin-top:1px;margin-left:1px;"></iframe>
</body>
<script>
    var eventTime = new Date();

    function activeEvent() {
        eventTime = new Date();
    }

    var height = 0;
    var width = 0;
    resize();

    function setTitle(message) {
        document.title = message;
    }

    function resize() {
        height = document.body.clientHeight - 2;
        width = document.body.clientWidth - 2;
        if (height < 480) height = 480;
        if (width < 640) width = 640;
        document.getElementById("iframe").height = height;
        document.getElementById("iframe").width = width;
    }
    setInterval("resize()", 1000);
    document.getElementById("iframe").src = "http://xxxxxx.com:80/lhscm/framework/mainform/navui/nav3mainform.do?height=" + height + "&width=" + width;
</script>

</html>
```

But using Selenium  `driver.page_source` can't get the `src` link generated `HTML`.

So, how can I get the content ?

Comment: and i use firefox firebug,  i can get the html elements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of your page seem to be completely located inside an `iframe`, so to get it you should switch to this frame. Try following:

```
driver.switch_to_frame('iframe')
source = driver.page_source
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: Dear Andersson，and i have anther question，in the js generated html，it have several iframe， and all the frame haven't id、name，how can i switch the frame i wanted to，thanks a lot！！

Comment: You can match `iframe` with `XPath`, for example,  `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="some_class_name"]'))`